# After move to dotnet core 2.2 on Linux, connecting to our Azure SQL database often throws pre-login handshake error

Tags: sql-server, azure, .net-core

Last week we migrated our production environment from .NET Framework 4.6.2 to .NET Core 2.2. Everything works as expected except we now often get the following error when we connect to the database:

```html
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 - Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

Our production environment used to run on a Windows 32 bit App Service plan in Azure. In this environment we almost never had any issues with pre-login handshakes.

Now suddenly after we've moved to Linux 64 bit containers, these errors start to pop up a few times a day.

I've searched the internet for a solution, but I cannot find it. Does anyone have an idea of what we should do?

This is our connection string:

```html
Server=tcp:{server_url},1433;Data Source={server_url};Initial Catalog={database};Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};Password={your_password};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Max Pool Size=500;
```

EDIT: Just to be clear: most of the connections to the SQL database succeed. We have many users on our server. However, the amount of unsuccessful connections has increased significantly.

Comment: The error complains about TLS. Have you configured it, eg installed any required certificates? Check [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-encrypted-connections?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Try [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/30147), or any of the ones related to it. There are many reasons why a TLS connection could fail, most of them having to do with the underlying OS/lib/runtime support and not the framework.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the server from inside the container using eg `sqlcmd` ? If not, you won't be able to connect from .NET Core either

Comment: I've updated the original question with a remark. The above mentioned solutions are all for cases where it never works.

Comment: The core issue remains the same: TLS negotiation fails, but you're not going to find out more from the application logs or the (surface) stack traces, as this stuff is essentially happening on a level below the `System.Data.SqlClient` code. There could be a resource problem, or an obscure timing issue. You've got the double whammy of this being .NET Core and Linux, both of which complicate tracing as opposed to vanilla Windows. There's presumably some way of getting internal tracing to work, but I wouldn't know the steps. You could start off with an external network trace for starters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out what was going on.
We were leaking connections in another piece of code (and to another server). The responses were not disposed correctly. Since the allowed amount of open connections was smaller in Linux, we ran into this problem more quickly.

It's too bad the exception message is so ambiguous, but I can understand that it's difficult to raise a less ambiguous exception.

Anyway, for people looking for an answer to the same problem: do a "netstat -an" on your server when you run into this issue and check whether you're not looking connections.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue but haven't figured out what's wrong. Same thing that happened to you, a few errors a day at random times that have been getting more frequent. How were you leaking connections to another server?

Comment: We weren't having the typical "using" blocks in our code.
Did you run netstat -an like I proposed?

Comment: Yeah, netstat -an looks good, it may be something different in our case but it's very hard to troubleshoot.

Comment: We ended up tweaking the EF retry mechanism to handle this specific error and retry, and so far so good. It was an occasional error that seems to have been caused by occasional connection losses.

Comment: Glad you found something!